# Anylogic pick random agent in a Rack System

Tags: storage, anylogic, rack

Currently I am trying to get AGVs to pick a random Shelve in a Rack System, drive to the depot and then return the shelve back to the location. My Problem is that the AGVs Picks the Agent top down and each Agent only one time. I want the AGVs to pick random shelves in each rack system and some shelves several time just like in a real refs.  [I also attach a picture of the processes for each Storage class.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaXBY.png)

I don't know how to create this. I tried it by turning off the resource selection, but It did not work the way I wanted to do. I also tried to get rid of the class storage and only pick one class system, but I do not think this is the right way. It would be Very nice if someone can please help me. If I want to put a queue block in front of the moveAtopickup1 annylogic asks me to pick an agent location, but I can not select the fitting rack system only nodes.